# JavaScript DateTime Conversion Decreasing one day

Tags: javascript

When I am converting date 2012-01-01 by using following javascript code.

```
var dtmRDate = new Date('2012-01-01');
```

it returns the result:

```
Sat Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 2011
```

It seems like that decreasing one day. What should I do to resolve this issue.

Comment: it looks like a timezone issue, by default the parser will assume the input to be in UTC timezone and when converting to string representation it uses local time zone

Comment: You can try `new Date('2012-01-01 EST')`

Answer (score 0):

it looks like a timezone issue, by default the parser will assume the input to be in UTC timezone and when converting to string representation it uses local time zone

You can try `new Date('2012-01-01 EST')`